# User Role And Permission

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise

I am facing a problem regarding user role and permission while working on sharepoint 2010. Basically I need to show list items in which login user department match with list item department.

I am follow this link tutorial mentioned below,

[Tutorial Link](http://www.spsamples.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-filtering.html)

It filter the department on button click instead of list page loading first time. How could i filter the list items based on user departments on list page load?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of these ?

Filter by USER's property:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2008/06/24/how-to-filter-a-sharepoint-list-based-on-the-log-in-user-s-properties-e-g-department-etc.aspx
- http://www.spsamples.com/2012/02/filter-sharepoint-list-view-on-user.html

Or using and OOTB Web Part known as Current User Filter http://www.click2learn.ch/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=29

Comment: C. Marius, yes i tried above links but the problem is list is not filtering on first time page load. It filter list on page refresh(in second link) or button click(in first link, first solution).

Comment: yes i tried above links but the problem is list is not filtering on first time list click. It filter list on page refresh(in second link) or button click(in first link, first solution).